# Pass object attribute from previous sklearn pipeline step as argument to next step method

Tags: python, pipeline, random-forest, tfidfvectorizer, gridsearchcv

**tl;dr**: Is there any way to call `.get_feature_names()` on the fit *and* transformed data from the previous step of the pipeline to use as a hyperparameter in the next step of the pipeline?

---

I have a `Pipeline` that includes fitting and transforming text data with `TfidfVectorizer`, and then runs a `RandomForestClassifier`. I want to `GridSearchCV` across various levels of `max_features` in the classifier, based on the number of features that the transformation produced from the text.

```
#setup pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(max_df=.4,
                            min_df=3,
                            norm='l1',
                            stop_words='english',
                            use_idf=False)),
    ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1,
                                  criterion='entropy',
                                  n_estimators=800))
])

#setup parameter grid
params = {
    'rf__max_features': np.arange(1, len(vect.get_feature_names()),1)
}
```

#### Instantiating returns the following error:

`NameError: name 'vect' is not defined`

#### Edit:

This is more relevant (and not explicated in the sample code) if I were modulating a parameter of the `TfidfVectorizer` such as `ngram_range`, one could see how this could change the number of features output to the next step...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter grid gets populated before anything in the pipeline is fitted, so you can't do this directly.  You might be able to monkey-patch the gridsearch, [like here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/60107/55122), but I'd expect it to be substantially harder since your second parameter depends on the results of fitting the first step.

I think the best approach, while it won't produce exactly what you're after, is to just use fractional values for `max_features`, i.e. a percentage of the columns coming out of the vectorizer.

If you really want a score for every integer `max_features`, I think the easiest way may be to have two nested grid searches, the inner one only instantiating the parameter space when its `fit` is called:

```
estimator = RandomForestClassifier(
    random_state=1,
    criterion='entropy',
    n_estimators=800
    )

class MySearcher(GridSearchCV):
    def fit(self, X, y):
        m = X.shape[1]
        self.param_grid = {'max_features': np.arange(1, m, 1)}
        return super().fit(X, y)

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(max_df=.4,
                             min_df=3,
                             norm='l1',
                             stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=False)),
    ('rf', MySearcher(estimator=estimator, 
                      param_grid={'fake': ['passes', 'check']}))
])
```

Now the search results will be awkwardly nested (best values of, say, `ngram_range` give you a refitted copy of `pipe`, whose second step will itself have a best value of `max_features` and a corresponding refitted random forest).  Also, the data available for the inner search will be a bit smaller.